# Obtain data points from a density plot

Tags: plotting

I have a density plot, for example

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x*y],{x,0,2pi},{y,0,2pi}].
```

Then I would like to collect points from this densityplot into a file so that I can always use ListDensityPlot to draw these points again, or I may draw these points by some other software.

I read several posts on how to do that for Plot, but how can I generalize them to `DensityPlot`?

Answer (score 5):

```
data = Reap[DensityPlot[Sin[x*y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y, Sin[x*y]}]]][[2, 1]];

ListPlot3D[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

compare to

```
 DensityPlot[Sin[x*y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! It works. I really need to learn more about Reap function.

Comment: For each point `{x,y}` your solution evaluate the function `f[x,y]' to `DensityPlot` twice: one time for the `DensityPlot` value itself, and one for the `Sow`, as you put back `f[x,y]` in `Sow`. Is there a way to call `f[x,y]` on time only  ?

Comment: @PierreL. the only way to evaluate only once, that I know about, is to generate the data off-line using `Table` command, then use `DensityPlot` but the reason for doing the above, is to use the same sampling as that used by `DensityPlot` which can be different and not uniform as what one might pick using `Table`. Sometimes `Plot` uses an adaptive sampling.  I

Comment: @Nasser yes, unfortunately `DensityPlot` cannot return easily the values on the grid with the plot itself.

Answer (score 2):

how about this?

```
lists = Table[
   Sin[x*y], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/20}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/20}];

ListDensityPlot[lists, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Or like this

```
lists = DensityPlot[Sin[x*y], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}][[1, 
    1]];

ListDensityPlot[{#1, #2, Sin[#1 #2]} & @@@ lists, Mesh -> None]
```

Comment: Thank you. So Table[] divides the domains {x,0,2pi} and {y,0,2pi} automatically?

Comment: Automatical dividing number is '1', but If you make more dividing point, then do like this.

Answer (score 2):

Though `DensityPlot` only contains color info for z value.

However, you could obtain data from equivalent `Plot3D`

```
plot=Plot3D[Sin[x*y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

If you see the `plot//FullForm`, you can find point data contained in `GraphicsComplex[list of data,__]`

So to extract data, it is as simple as

```
plot[[1,1]]
```

You can check this by

```
ListDensityPlot[plot[[1,1]]]
```